# make a table of data in google docs if cells in spreadsheet contain data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, append, google-docs, google-forms

I am trying to write a script which creates a table in a google docs file with the results after a user has submitted a form.

In the form the user can enter up to 16 invoices and 16 payments; however on my summary pdf I don't want to display a table full of empty cells if the user has only entered one invoice.

I tried to write an if statement to say "If "invoice number" cell is not empty, then create a table row, if not, do nothing", but it creates the rows anyway even when the cells are empty and I can't quite figure out why.

Anyone have any ideas? Here's the code:

```
  var invoiceData = [['Invoice Number', 'Invoice Amount', 'Due Date of Invoice']]; 
  table1 = copyBody.appendTable(invoiceData);
  var tab1row1=table1.appendTableRow();

 if (sheet3.getRange("A20").getValue() ==! 0);{
tab1row1.appendTableCell(sheet3.getRange("A3").getValue());
tab1row1.appendTableCell("£" + sheet3.getRange("B3").getValue());
tab1row1.appendTableCell(sheet3.getRange("C3").getValue());
```

And the same code repeated for rows up to row 16 (but with changed numbers obviuosly).

The cell A20 (which is the one specified within the IF statement) is a cell containing the formula =VALUE(A3).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `not` operator, which is an exclamation point, can't be after the equal signs.

```
function testAfunction() {
  Logger.log(1===1); //true
  Logger.log(1!==99);  //true
  Logger.log(1==!99);  //false
};
```

Also, remove the extra semi-colon.

Should be:

```
if (sheet3.getRange("A20").getValue() !== 0) {
```